# Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, passport.js

im learning abt passport and jwt auth and i got an error says `Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"`

here my auth.js

```js
const passport = require('passport')

module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('jwt', function (err, user){
        if (err || !user){
            res.status(403).send({
            error: "you dont have access to this resource"                
            })
        }else{
            req.user = user
            next()
        }
    })(req, res, next)
}
```

can anyone spot which one is wrong? thanks

Comment: are you sure you are using correct dependencies? check out this tutorial https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314

Comment: There's a specific package for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt